# Conditionally add values to a new column and replace values in the conditioning column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I am working on a project where I need to read files into my environment and afterwards based on the row's name change a value and add new values to new columns: i.e.

```
     X1     Area   Mean   Min    Max              file_row_name
     55    0.165  31.384   4      82   ./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv
     56    0.097  45.867   4      121  ./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv
     168   0.042  28.252  20      49    ./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-25-50-10x-1-1.csv
```

So in the example I want to look at each row's `file_row_name` and if the rows have the same name, create two variables: `Conc` & `Rep` and replace the values at `file_row_name` so as to look like this:

```
     X1     Area   Mean   Min    Max              file_row_name        Conc     Rep
     55    0.165  31.384   4      82                     T0             12.5     3
     56    0.097  45.867   4      121                    T0             12.5     3
     168   0.042  28.252  20      49                     T0             25       1
```

So far what I've done is:

```
my_df$Conc[my_df$file_row_name  == "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv"]  <-  12.5
my_df$Rep[my_df$file_row_name  == "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv"]  <- 3
my_df$file_row_name[my_df$file_row_name  == "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv"]  <-  "T0"
my_df$Conc[my_df$file_row_name == "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3.csv"] <- 12.5
my_df$Rep[my_df$file_row_name  == "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3.csv"]  <- 3
my_df$file_row_name[my_df$file_row_name  == "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3.csv"]  <-  "T0"
```

But this takes too long and when I try an `if` clause:

```
if(my_df$file_row_name %in% c("./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv",
                              "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3.csv")){
  my_df$Conc = "12.5"
  my_df$Rep = 3
  my_df$file_row_name = "T0"
}
```

it tells me that:

```
Warning message:
In if (my_df$file_row_name %in% c("./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv",  :
  the condition has longitud > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And if I manage to bypass that warning message with another code piece, basically the columns `file_row_name` `Conc` and `Rep` get replaced with the same value and nothing is changed based on condition.

Comment: `if` is not vectorized, you can use `ifelse`

Comment: But it doesn't let me add columns i think, or I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Can you check the solution posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if` (which is not vectorized), we create a logical row index and use to assign

```
i1 <- my_df$file_row_name %in% c("./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3-1.csv",
                          "./Fluorescence Analysis/T0-12.5-150-10x-3.csv")

mydf[i1, c("Conc", "Rep", "file_row_name")] <- list("12.5", 3, "T0")
```